# How can you specify the FFT length in cv::dft as in Python numpy.fft.rfft

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, fft

I have been successfully do the FFT in python using numpy.fft.rfft(). Now, I want to port this code to C++.

After researching at this topics [How can I port code that uses numpy.fft.rfft from python to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295954/how-can-i-port-code-that-uses-numpy-fft-rfft-from-python-to-c), I am able to use the cv::dft to do the FFT. However, the problem is that with numpy.fft.rfft(), there is an additional parameters that is the **fft length**, and I cannot find it in cv.

My Python code is as follow:

```
window_frame = np.array([1,2,3,4])
fft_length = 10
np.abs(np.fft.rfft(window_frame, int(fft_length)))
```

The result is:

```
[10. , 8.16620583 , 4.25325404, 2.51258479 , 2.62865556 , 2.]
```

The length is (fft_length/2)+1.

In C++, I perform the following code:

```
std::vector<double> t;
cv::dft(window_frame, t)
```

The result is:

```
[10. -2., 2., -2.]
```

**How can I achieve the same result as in Python version?**

---

Updated:

I have tried the following solution:

1. I resize the the input "window_frame" to the fft_length (padded with zeros)
2. Perform the cv::dft on the new input
3. Resize the output to (fft_length/2) + 1

   std::vector t;
   window_frame.resize(fft_length);
   cv::dft(window_frame, t);
   t.resize((fft_length/2)+1);

The result is:

```
[10 2.30902 -7.83297 -4.04508 -1.31433 1.19098 2.21238 1.54508 -2.12663 -2]
```

which is the same as in the Python version when apply np.fft.rfft()

```
[10 + 0j, 2.309 - 7.832j, -4.045 - 1.3143j, 1.19098 + 2.212j, 1.54508 -2.126j, -2 + 0j]
```

Now, How can I perform the np.abs on this data? Do the first and the last element have only the real part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the FFT length in your Python code, the input signal is truncated or padded with 0s, to the requested length, before applying the FFT algorithm.

In C++ you could do, for example,

```
windows_frame.resize(fft_length, 0);
cv::dft(windows_frame, t);
```

OpenCV has its own unique way of representing the real-valued frequency domain, it is different from what NumPy produces. NumPy outputs N/2+1 complex values (note! this uses integer division). OpenCV outputs N real values. [Read the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft) to figure out how to interpret the output of `cv::dft` for real-valued input and output. In short, the first array element corresponds to the zero frequency component (which is always real-valued), and subsequent array elements correspond to the real and imaginary components of the first half of the frequency spectrum. For even-sized arrays, the last array element correspond to the frequency component N/2 (which is always real-valued). For odd-sized arrays, frequency component N/2 is also complex, and both its components are present (though this is not made explicit in the documentation).

- Even size: `[r0, r1, i1, r2, i2, ... rN/2]`
- Odd size: `[r0, r1, i1, r2, i2, ... rN/2 iN/2]`

Comment: I haven't been able to achieve the same result with your solution. As I read in the doc, the output size depends on the cv::dft, so resize t before apply the FFT does not work. I also tried to resize the input "window_frame", but that doesn't produce the same result either.

Comment: @AnhVoNguyenNhat: Sorry for the wrong code, it is the input that should be resized, as I had written in the text. It is indeed likely that the output is not identical to what NumPy produces, OpenCV has it’s own unique format...

Comment: Yes, I think so too. So I did resize the input and update the post. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @AnhVoNguyenNhat: I've edited the answer to address the last addition to your question. I hope this is clear enough.